# Centimorgans and relationship

Tags: autosomal-dna

If two people share 327 centimorgans and 19 DNA segments and are first cousins 1x removed, is it possible that one of them is my 2nd cousin 1x removed if we share 353 centimorgans and 17 DNA segments.  I am trying to determine my relationship with them.
Our DNA matches came back as:
Susan and Bell share 327 centimorgans and 19 DNA segments (they are 1st cousins 1x removed).
Susan and I share 353 centimorgans and 17 DNA segments.
Bell and I share 162 centimorgans and 9 DNA segments.

Answer (score 1):

I think you wrote the incorrect data. You can't have at the same time two different distances to one person ("364 centimorgans and 17 DNA" vs "353 centimorgans and 17 DNA segments"). Please correct your question.

Also as stated in [Probability of Specific Relationship from AncestryDNA?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/13418) you missed a lot of details. Yes, generally you and Susan may be 2nd cousin 1x removed. But you need to double check paper genealogy and use additional data. The clue may be not only in the size of overlap segments but in WHAT are these segments. You need so-called chromosome browser tool to visualize the overlapped segments. If there is no such tool on site of company where you got tests, you may upload the raw autosomal data to 3rd party service called [GEDMATCH](https://www.gedmatch.com/). It provides additional and very useful tools for comparing test taken from different people. Also you may find "matches" with others.

Comment: That you for pointing out the typo - corrected.  My father was adopted and my DNA matches know very little about their family.  I think I have exhausted US records and have been on an Italian website as well.  I guess what I really want to know is, can a 2nd cousin or 2nd cousin 1x removed share the same centimorgans as a 1cousin 1x removed.  Also, can you have a 1 cousin 1x removed share twice the centimorgans (638) than that of another 1 cousin 1x removed (327).  I am trying to compare relationship with what they think they know.  Thank you for your feedback.

Comment: _Also, can you have a 1 cousin 1x removed share twice the centimorgans (638) than that of another 1 cousin 1x removed (327_

Unfortunately, yes, it can. It makes the research more difficult, I think.